# OnClickListener and OnLongClickListener not firing in Launcher

Tags: android, launcher

I have this

```
public class Launcher extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

but nothing happens after clicking...

Comment: You might want to read this Stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866379/whats-the-effect-of-implementing-the-onclicklistener-with-an-activity

Comment: You have forgot to register your onClickListener method for your Button..

Comment: Do I really need a button? The goal is to click any part of the home screen.

Comment: Do you want to perform a action on click or onLong click event of menu launcher icon??

Comment: No, it's like default action when u press onLong on home screen,u get a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your buttons/widgets for `onClickListener`?

For ex;

```
  Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: @user2976216 If you want to launch `onClickListener` on clicking any part on screen register `onClickListener` for whole homescreen layout.Like `LinearLayout/RelativeLayout`. It won't fire simply unless you register for it.

Comment: @user2976216 pleasure to help:)